# How to use Structure map for DI if some constructor parameters need to be passed manually

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am facing a situation where my Class constructor takes 2 parameters. One parameter needs to be passed manually by the calling object while the other parameter should be injectd by Structuremap. I want to expose only one constructor that takes parameter value that should be passed manually. I want to hide the second parameter as it should be handled by Structure map itself. Can anyone  suggest how it can be done.

I have a scenario like this

```
public class ProcessPayments
{
    public ProcessPayments(String accountNumber, IProcessPayments paymentProcesser)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to expose the constructor with only first parameter like so

```
var P = new ProcessPayments("123");
```

I want Structure Map to automatically inject the IProcessPayments dependency for me based on my configuration.

How can I achieve this?

I can do something like this in my constructor

```
public ProcessPayments(String accountNumber)
{
    _AccountNumber = accountNumber;
    _ProcessPayments = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProcessPayments >();
}
```

But this would mean that now I have a dependency on Structure Map itself and I don't like  this option. Any other elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `accountNumber` is a runtime dependency/value (it can change from call to call). Do not mix runtime values with compile/registration time dependencies. Instead pass the `accountNumber` on using a method:

```
public class ProcessPayments
{
    public ProcessPayments(IProcessPayments paymentProcesser) { ... }

    public void Process(String accountNumber) { ... }
}
```

Or, if that's not appropriate, create a factory:

```
public class ProcessPaymentsFactory : IProcessPaymentsFactory
{
    public ProcessPaymentsFactory(IProcessPayments paymentProcesser) { ... }

    public ProcessPayments Create(String accountNumber)
    {
        return new ProcessPayments(accountNumber, this.paymentProcesser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Steven your answer makes perfect sense to me however in my current case I am passing the parameter taken from the constructor to the constructor of the base class. I guess I can modify the base class to take parameter in method rather than constructor too. Otherwise I can use a factory. Your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Steven I have one small related question that I would like you to answer so I am not posting it again. I believe that if an Object needs some value to perform its functionality, it should be disclosed in the constructor. Like if for example there is a class that gets json data from some url then maybe URL should be set via constructor. Your answer has got me thinking is this approach right or not? Plz give your valuable feedback.

Comment: @AfrazAli: In that example, the url seems like a configuration value. It won't change during the lifetime of the application. You'll pass that through the constructor.